# How to add eclipse String shortcuts?

Tags: eclipse

For example, if I type `sysout` and then `ctrl + space`, it'll automaticlly fill `System.out.println();`.

How can I add a custom shortcut? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Window -> Preferences -> New -> Java -> Editor -> Templates
```

**Name:**     MainProgram (which is like sysout)

**Pattern:**

```
public static void main(String args[]){

}
```

And then ok.

Now If you type MainProgram and Ctrl+space which gives you the full program..

Answer (score 1):

access the menu, `window>preference`, type the name of your language, at threeview select `editor>template` click at new put your template and OK

Answer (score 0):

```
window-preferences-General-key
```

then set you custom key on "content assistant" item